# How to simplify for loops in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, for-loop, numpy

I'm a C and MATLAB user. When I started learning Python (a week ago) I noticed that I don't use full potential of MATLAB, in particular array operations. I use for loops often, probably because I learnt programming in C.

In a previous tip, I learnt to use `cumsum` and other efficient array operations, for example:

```
alpha = [1e-4,1e-3,1e-4,1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-6,1e-3];
zeta = alpha / (dz*dz)
nz = 101
l=[0.3,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2];
wz = cumsum(l*(nz-1));
nl = lenght(l);
```

Is it possible simplify the following code in Python (Numpy) or MATLAB?

```
      A = zeros(nz,nz);
      i=1;
      for j = 2:wz(i)-1
        A(j,j-1) = zeta(1,1);
        A(j,j) = -2*zeta(1,1);
        A(j,j+1) = zeta(1,1); % layer 1 nodes 
      end

      %cicle to n-layers
      for i=2:nl
          for j=wz(i-1):wz(i-1)
              A(j,j-1) = zeta(1,i-1);
              A(j,j) = -zeta(1,i-1)-zeta(1,i);
              A(j,j+1) = zeta(1,i); 
          end

          for j=wz(i-1)+1:wz(i)
              A(j,j-1) = zeta(1,i);
              A(j,j) = -2*zeta(1,i);
              A(j,j+1) = zeta(1,i);
          end

      end
end
```

Comment: It would be easier for us if you would explain in a sentence or two what the code is supposed to do, not just give us the plain code...

Comment: @Hans This code belongs to an 1D Equation Heat  Solver applied to a multilayer.
alpha is an array with the diffusivities per layer, l is an array with the heights per layer, wz is an array which aggregates the cumulative sum of points (discrete points) and A is the "state matrix".
After calculate state matrix, I'll implement the ode solver.

Comment: @marco: in case you didn't realise, MATLAB has various [ODE solvers](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/ode23.html) built in, while for Python, you can find ODE solvers in [Scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html).

Comment: I'll use a built in ODE solver. But matrix A is an Input of solver.
THis code is corret (solves the problem) but it is not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the code below after having a chance to run it on my machine side by side yours.  There are still a couple of questions (is A suppose to get larger in the final loop?, what is dz?).  The problem you ran into before running this was that I forgot idx_matrix had to be logical.

```
dz=0.1;
alpha = [1e-4,1e-3,1e-4,1e-1,1e-2,1e-3,1e-6,1e-3];
zeta = alpha / (dz*dz);
nz = 101;
l=[0.3,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2];
wz = cumsum(l*(nz-1));
nl = length(l);

A = zeros(nz);
i=1;

%replaces 1st loop
j_start = 2;
j_end = wz(i)-1;

idx_matrix = false(size(A));
idx_matrix(j_start:j_end,j_start:j_end) = eye(j_end-j_start+1);
A(idx_matrix) = -2*zeta(1,1);

idx_matrix(idx_matrix) = false;
idx_matrix(j_start:j_end,j_start-1:j_end-1) = eye(j_end-j_start+1);
A(idx_matrix) = zeta(1,1);

idx_matrix(idx_matrix) = false;
idx_matrix(j_start:j_end,j_start+1:j_end+1) = eye(j_end-j_start+1);
A(idx_matrix) = zeta(1,1);

%cicle to n-layers
for i=2:nl

    %replaces 3rd loop
    j_start = wz(i-1);
    A(j_start,j_start) = -zeta(1,i-1)-zeta(1,i);
    A(j_start,j_start-1) = zeta(1,i-1);
    A(j_start,j_start+1) = zeta(1,i);

    %replaces 4th loop
    j_start = wz(i-1)+1;
    j_end = min(wz(i),size(A,2)-1);
    idx_matrix = false(size(A));
    idx_matrix(j_start:j_end,j_start:j_end) = eye(j_end-j_start+1);
    A(idx_matrix) = -2*zeta(1,i);

    idx_matrix(idx_matrix) = false;
    idx_matrix(j_start:j_end,j_start-1:j_end-1) = eye(j_end-j_start+1);
    A(idx_matrix) = zeta(1,i);

    idx_matrix(idx_matrix) = false;
    idx_matrix(j_start:j_end,j_start+1:j_end+1) = eye(j_end-j_start+1);
    A(idx_matrix) = zeta(1,i);

end
```

Comment: thank you for answering.
Your code has an error 
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
A(idx_matrix) = -2*zeta(1,1);

It's so early in the code, that I can't figure what you want to do.

Yes, third cycle, can be an assignment, I didn't find a better way to this instruction. (This represents the boundary between layers, if you read my code description to @Hans)

Comment: AHh, and "you're A matrix" is an array (A=zeros(nz)) is an error or not?

Comment: A = zeros(nz) is the same as A = zeros(nz,nz)

Comment: Did you intend for A to get larger as this code continues to run?  The final for loop adds a column to A because wz(i) == size(A,2) and A(j,j+1) indexes out of bounds, so another column is added.  Also, you never defined dz.

Comment: you're right. you're code works. However, in the final loop the "zeta" fators are not mulpying per coefficients.
Is it possible keep general? If the size of l is chaging?

Comment: This code produces the same output as the one posted in the question.  The only difference is I changed the way the index in the 4th loop are calculated (using the min function).  I assume you didn't want to change the size of A.  Other than that, this code should produce identical results.  If I were you, I would run the code side by side, and see if the problem is also in the original you posted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6831/discussion-between-marco-and-majorapus)

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your loops, you can use the function `spdiags`.

http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/spdiags.html

For instance your first loop can be written as:

```
A=full(spdiags(repmat([zeta(1,1),-2*zeta(1,1),zeta(1,1)],wz(i),1),[-1 0 1],wz(i),wz(i)))
```

Comment: thank you for the reference, but this don't resolve my problem =)
I'm trying to find a way to simplify the problem, in other words transform the iteration problem in vector problem

Comment: I edited the answer to show you how to use `spdiags` in your case,

Comment: I didn't get it, and when I paste the code in Matlab, returns
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> spdiags at 114
         a((len(k)+1):len(k+1),:) = [i i+d(k) B(i+(m>=n)*d(k),k)];

Comment: works, but the results are different. "My matrix" has a diagonal (with 3 values) with 100,-200,100. "yours" has always 100.
You're matrix has 30,30 size, which is normal, because it is only the first part of cycle.

Comment: I forgot to mention @Oli in last comment =)

Comment: ok, I edited. But you can read the documentation of `spdiags`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6795/discussion-between-marco-and-oli)